# Viewbag Dropdown list from javascript always undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I try to make dynamically multiple input with dropdown list,
My select list is using viewbag and the result is always undefined.

The Viewbag List

```
private void ToolCategories(object selectedcat = null)
{
      var catQuery = from d in db.Toolcategories
                     where d.In == "AD" 
                     orderby d.CategoryName
                     select d;
      SelectList ToolCategories = new SelectList(catQuery, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", selectedcat);
      ViewBag.ToolCategories = ToolCategories;
}
```

The View

```
@using System.Text.Json;

<script>
var resin = document.createElement("div");
resin.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");
var resinGrup = document.createElement("div");
resinGrup.setAttribute("class", "form-grup");
var resinLabel = document.createElement("label");
resinLabel.setAttribute("class", "form-label fs-6");
resinLabel.innerHTML = "Tool";
var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(ViewBag.ToolCategories));
var resinSelect = document.createElement("select");
resinSelect.setAttribute("id", "CategoryId");
resinSelect.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
resinSelect.setAttribute("required", "");
resinSelect.setAttribute("name", `[${toolID}].ToolCategories`);
$.each(jsonObj, function (index, ToolCategories) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = ToolCategories.CategoryId;
  option.text = ToolCategories.CategoryName;
  resinSelect.append(option);
})
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My select list is using viewbag and the result is always undefined.

Well, your `undefined dropdown` is pretty obvious because you have used [`SelectList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which keeps data as  `Text` and `Value` pairs. Thus, you are binding it within your `$.each` loop as `CategoryId` and`CategoryName` but the items is not residing there as it is. As you can see below:

[image]

**Solution:**

You need to modify your `option` binding as `option.value = ToolCategories.Value;` instead of `ToolCategories.CategoryId;`

Thereofore, complete code would be:

```
$.each(jsonObj, function (index, ToolCategories) {
                console.log(ToolCategories);
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = ToolCategories.Value;
                option.text = ToolCategories.Text;
                resinSelect.append(option);
            });
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note: If you still need further details on it, [please have a look on our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Sorryy for the late responss, silly me to get the ridiculous error like that. Thank you again for helping me once again

Comment: Its alright and thanks for your response. In addition, glad to assist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems everything looks fine except below 2 lines, in your view file.. Replace your Category Id with Value and CategoryName with Text.

option.value = ToolCategories.Value;
option.text = ToolCategories.Text;

You are getting undefined as it failed to find values but required values mapped to different properties.